# Updating datepicker based on days available based on database values

Tags: php, jquery, html, arrays

I am currently trying to disable certain days on the jquery datepicker based on values which are taken from a mysql database and stored in a php array. I am having trouble converting the php array into jquery and then reading the values to disable the days which have not been selected to be available for the user. Could anyone walk me through what I have to do to create this functionality. I am a bit lost in the process after encoding the php array into json

```
 $daysavailquery = "SELECT Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, 
 Saturday, Sunday FROM miiLearning_tutorAvail WHERE id = 
 $id";

$daysavailresult = mysqli_query($conn, $daysavailquery);

$daysavailarray = mysqli_fetch_array($daysavailresult);

//Convert days avail to json
$DaysAvailJSON = json_encode($daysavailarray);
echo $DaysAvailJSON;

<script>
        $( function() {


            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
                var daysAvailArray = <?php echo json_encode($daysavailarray) ?>
                beforeShowDay: function(date) {

                var day = date.getDay();
                console.log(day);

                if (day == 0 && daysAvailArray[0]==1)
                  return [true];
                if (day == 1 && daysAvailArray[0]==1)
                  return [true];
                if (day == 2 && daysAvailArray[0]==1)
                  return [true];
                if (day == 3 && daysAvailArray[0]==1)
                  return [true];
                if (day == 4 && daysAvailArray[0]==1)
                  return [true];
                if (day == 5 && daysAvailArray[0]==1)
                  return [true];
                if (day == 6 && daysAvailArray[0]==1)
                  return [true];

                return [false];
              }
            });
        } );
    </script>

<div class="form-group">
     <label for="datepicker">Pick a date</label>
     <input type="text" date-date- format="yy-mm-dd" name="datepicker" 
id="datepicker" class="form-control" required>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the code? Which datepicker are you using? We need a better explanation of your problem

Comment: Apologies, will post code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that the table contains true or false value for each day.

```
$daysavailarray = mysqli_fetch_array($daysavailresult);
// should be have associate array
//[ 'monday' => '1', 'Sunday' => '0']
// we don't need the day name so we will use MYSQLI_NUM to have it as numerical index [ 0 => '1' , 1 => '0' ]
$daysavailarray = mysqli_fetch_array($daysavailresult, MYSQLI_NUM);
```

Now want to convert the php array to javascript array `json_encode` will do the job

`var daysAvailArray = <?php echo json_encode($daysavailarray) ?>;`

Because we have the day as index it will be easier to see if it false or not

```
var day = date.getDay();
console.log(day);
return daysAvailArray[day-1] ? [true] : [false];
```

The complete javascript code

```
<script>
    $( function() {
        var daysAvailArray = <?php echo json_encode($daysavailarray) ?>;
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var day = date.getDay();
                return (daysAvailArray[day-1] == '1') ? [true] : [false];                           
            }
        });
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: so to use this do I change the $daysavailarray = mysqli_fetch_array($daysavailresult); to $daysavailarray = mysqli_fetch_array($daysavailresult, MYSQLI_NUM);, then encode it and set the variable in js to var daysAvailArray = <?php echo json_encode($daysavailarray) ?>;?

Comment: Yes and remove all the if statements and replace the return with 
return daysAvailArray[day-1] ? [true] : [false];

Comment: var daysAvailArray = ["0","0","0","0","0","0","1"]; Currently I am having an unexpected syntax error pop up in this line.. not entriely sure whats going on

Comment: the syntax seems file inspect the page and post the whole javascript.

Comment: <script>
            $( function() {
                $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
                    var daysAvailArray = <?php echo json_encode($daysavailarray) ?>;
                    console.log(day);
                    
                    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                        var day = date.getDay();
                        console.log(day);
                        return daysAvailArray[day-1] ? [true] : false;
                  }
                });
            } );
        </script>

Comment: I updated my answer you will find the complete javascript code

Comment: oh thats worked great, the only issue I currently have is I stored the day values as either a 1 or 0 (Not a bool) so the function is making it impossible to book any days

Comment: you have to store the value as int in database. so 1 mean available and 0 not available. and in javascript compare as string because php will retrieve the values as string

Comment: Yeah I currently have then stored as 1s and 0s for true and false. Is the current return cycling through all elements of the array or just one? ie: return (daysAvailArray[day-1] == '1') ? [true] : [false];

Comment: it will be for each date in the calendar, the picker will send the date before rendering it the browser. Then var day = date.getDay(); will get the day of the week index. monday = 1 and sunday 7. Then will check in the daysAvailArray array if this date is available or not. day-1 because in php array monday = 0 and sunday = 6

Comment: I now have this working.. thank you very much sir I am very greatful